# Is this really THE Bill Gates ? Or a Prank account?

Tags: discussion, users

https://stackoverflow.com/users/442934/bill-gates

[image]

---

[Thanks](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/166608), [George](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/142114)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/users/442966/steve-jobs

Comment: looks like bill gates decided to cancel his account

Comment: same for steve ... such a shame

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging by this answer and the users email

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547169/best-program-you-have-written-in-assembly-language-so-far/3672758#3672758

### NO

Comment: What is the email? Please tell us!

Comment: I am assuming the `NO` is in responses to, "Or a prank account?" Since, I always assume people are referring to the most recently mentioned item.

Comment: @George I'll bet it's billgates@me.com :-)

Comment: What if it's `bill@microsoft.com`?

Comment: @George The email was ninjaturtle932@hotmail.com

Comment: @HoLyVieR spot on, do you have access to our database some how?

Comment: @waffles he probably decoded the Gravatar's email hash.

Answer (score 7):

Since MS Windows wasn't written by Bill Gates, I'd say that it's a prank account.

Comment: Good for laughs, though:)

Comment: @George: While i like laughs i don't think those answers belong into serious SO questions.

Comment: He didn't write DOS either. He bought it.

Comment: He did write "donkey" though. Good resume padding there.

Answer (score 2):

There is another one coming up, [Steve Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442966/steve-jobs). This might be funny *for one answer*, not when repeatedly spamming a non-comedy site... I'm getting annoyed and expect to run out of <strike>spam</strike> offensive flags soon.

Comment: Maybe we'll have them face each other!

Comment: PUPPET FIGHT!!!

Answer (score 1):

I never knew impersonators on Stack Overflow could be this funny. Would be twice as funny if he was the real deal though.

Also, judging by his description on his profile, you can already tell he isn't Bill Gates since he wasn't the one who wrote DOS and Windows.

Comment: Funny isn't the word I'd use.

Comment: It worries me that people are apparently depressed enough to find these posts the height of comedy

Comment: I'm surprised that my answer was voted down simply because I find it funny and not because it was a misleading/wrong answer.

Comment: @Terence: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work -- downvotes on meta mean disagreement, not a bad answer.

Comment: @Michael: I thought it was funny, but also spam and dangerous. I think this thread helped alert the mods, right?

Comment: @Josh, that or the spam flags.

Comment: @Josh, Sorry I was a bit hostile about the down vote. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Terence: don't worry about it, no problem. Meta is very different :-)

Comment: @rchern: For the record, I flagged as spam, too